# How do I find the count of columns before the first occurrence of LIKE?

Tags: sql, database, database-design, sqlite

Sorted on column Y

```
   X       Y        Z 
------------------------
|      |     A1  |     |
------------------------
|      |     B2  |     |
------------------------
|      |     C3  |     |
------------------------ -----Page 1
|      |     D3  |     |
------------------------
|      |     E4  |     |
------------------------
|      |     F5  |     |
------------------------ -----Page 2
|      |     G5  |     |
------------------------
|      |     F6  |     |
------------------------
|      |     G7  |     | -----Page 3
```

User has option to enter wild card search, i.e. - "`%5`"

I would like to return to the user page 2 (as it has the first occurrence of something followed by 5.) OR find out how many rows there are before the column containing `F5`

(SQLite with C API)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `MySQL`, resultset ordered by `X` and `X` is unique:

```
SELECT  COUNT(*)
FROM    mytable
WHERE   X <
        (
        SELECT  X
        FROM    mytable
        WHERE   y LIKE '%5'
        ORDER BY
                X
        LIMIT 1
        )
```

Comment: Found one issue with this, any suggestions - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705238/how-do-i-get-like-and-count-to-return-the-number-of-rows-less-than-a-value-not-in

Answer (score 1):

Assuming MSSQL, here's a roundabout way that kind of steps through the logic.. let me know if it doesn't help:

```
declare @perPage int
declare @searchString varchar(20)
declare @countBefore int
declare @firstMatch varchar(20)
declare @resultPage int

set @perPage = 3
set @searchString = '%5'

select @firstMatch = (select top 1 y from myTable where y like @searchString order by y)
select @countBefore = (select count(*) from myTable where y < @firstMatch)
select @resultPage = (@countBefore / @perPage) + 1
```